# Presto self join matching with a date column

Tags: sql, presto

I'm trying to figure out why presto returns the following results.

I have the following table of 4 dates:

```
pickup_week (date)
'2019-10-28'
'2019-11-04'
'2019-11-06'
'2019-12-16'
```

When I try this simple self join:

```
select 

w1.pickup_week as pu_w1,
w2.pickup_week as pu_w2

from week_user_list w1
join week_user_list w2 on w1.pickup_week = w2.pickup_week + interval '7' day 

order by w1.pickup_week
```

I get the following results:

```
w1.pickup_week   w2.pickup_week
2019-11-04       2019-10-28 
2019-11-11       2019-11-04
```

As you can see the join condition stated:

```
w1.pickup_week = w2.pickup_week + interval '7' day
```

But what I see in the return table is the opposite, w2.pickup_week is the former week and not the later as stated in the condition.

In this case, my desired output would be:

```
w1.pickup_week   w2.pickup_week
2019-10-28       2019-11-04       
2019-11-04       2019-11-11
```

I understand that reverting the condition to

```
w1.pickup_week = w2.pickup_week - interval '7' day
```

would provide the desired output, but I'm confused as to why and how come is that presto is returning these types of results, the condition stating seems un-intuitive to me.

What is happening here and what would be the correct way to think about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just have the logic backwards.  Use `-`:

```
select w1.pickup_week as pu_w1, w2.pickup_week as pu_w2
from week_user_list w1 join
     week_user_list w2
     on w1.pickup_week = w2.pickup_week - interval '7' day 
order by w1.pickup_week;
```

This is clearly stating the the `w1` value is *one week before* the `w2` value.  I think you just have a minor confusion here about the ordering of date/times and date arithmetic.